# How do I grep to a file without grepping the file that I am creating?

Tags: bash, grep, macos

I've just run this command:

```
grep "WindowsIdentity" -r . > windowsid.txt
```

I was expecting it to grep and then output to a file. However what is happening is it's grabbing it recurrsively.

Comment: Can't you put `windowsid.txt` in the parent directory, or some other directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of options to skip searching within the file being created.

1. Create the file in a directory that is not within the tree being searched. Example: `grep WindowsIdentity -r > ../windowsid.txt`
2. Use the `--exclude` option. Example: `grep WindowsIdentity -r --exclude=windowsid.txt > windowsid.txt`

Comment: This is great thank you!

Comment: Since the command is recursive, it should be noted that your second option will skip (exclude) *any* files named ```windowsid.txt```, even if they appear in subdirectories. But +1 for an answer I might not have thought of.